# Displaying the full name instead of full name

Tags: php, html

My login table has Username and Password fields. I want to display the user's full name rather than their username when they log in with their username and password. Instead of saying Welcome USERNAME on the next page, I want to say Welcome FULLNAME.

Here is the index.php or the login page in html:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="rows grid">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="username">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                </div>
                <!--Password-->
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="passWord" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                </div>
                <!--Submit Button-->
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submit" value="Login" required>
                <!--Register Link-->
                    <span class="registerLink">Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Register</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php
// Submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
// Store the names, password, email, number
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$passWord = $_POST['passWord'];
// Selecting from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE 
    usernames = '$userName' AND
    passwords = '$passWord'";
// Exceute the query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// Count the number of the account of the same username and password
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Counts the results into arrys
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// Check if theres account in database
if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['loginMessage'] = '<span class = "success">Welcome '.$userName.'</span>';
    header('location:' .SITEURL. 'dashboard.php');
    exit(); 
}
else{
    $_SESSION['noAdmin'] = '<span class = "fail">Please check your username and password and try again.</span>';
    header('location:' .SITEURL. 'index.php');
    exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the register.php or register link:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="rows grid">
                    <!--Full Name-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullName" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required>
                    </div>
                     <!--Username-->
                     <div class="row">
                        <label for="username">User Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                    </div>
                     <!--Email-->
                     <div class="row">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="emaiL" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                    </div>
                      <!--Mobile Number-->
                      <div class="row">
                        <label for="number">Mobile Number</label>
                        <input type="number" id="number" name="numbeR" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" required>
                    </div>
                    <!--Password-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="passWord" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <!--Submit Button-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submit" value="Register" required>
                    <!--Try ko aban aban uni idelete-->
                        <span class="registerLink">Have an account already? <a href="index.php">Login</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Note: I want to display the input fullname in the welcome dashboard.

Comment: First off, please change your select query to parameterized prepared statement to avoid SQL inject attacks.

Comment: When you are registering, you must be saving the Full Name and other details in database. So when you are verifying username and password on login you are fetching all fields (SELECT *), in the $row output you would be getting the whole row from database. Try to print that in the html and see at what key/position is the full name stored. (For ex: If you have full_name field in database then it must be at $row['full_name'] and so forth)

Comment: Well, you explicitly use `$userName` in there: `$_SESSION['loginMessage'] = '<span class = "success">Welcome '.$userName.'</span>';` ... What about changing that to use the user data you receive back from your database query? So something like `$_SESSION['loginMessage'] = '<span class = "success">Welcome '.$row->fullName.'</span>';` where `fullName` needs to be the name of the column storing the full name in your database, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please change your select query to parameterized prepared statement to avoid SQL injection attacks
2. To display the "fullname", just fetch the db record say into an associative array say `$row` and use `$row["fullname"]` (or `$row["fullName"]` if the field name is actually `fullName`)

Hence, change the block:

```
/// other code
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE 
    usernames = '$userName' AND
    passwords = '$passWord'";
// Exceute the query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// Count the number of the account of the same username and password
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Counts the results into arrys
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// Check if theres account in database
if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['loginMessage'] = '<span class = "success">Welcome '.$userName.'</span>';
    header('location:' .SITEURL. 'dashboard.php');
    exit(); 
}
/// other code
```

to

```
<?php
/// other code
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE usernames = ? AND passwords = ?";

$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("ss", $userName,$passWord );
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$num = $result->num_rows;

if ($num == 1){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['loginMessage'] = '<span class = "success">Welcome '.$row["fullname"].'</span>';
    header('location:' .SITEURL. 'dashboard.php');
    exit(); 
}
/// other code
?>
```